# Почему одновременно происходит только два соединения с сайтом через WebProxy?

Tags: c#, proxy

Пишу навороченый прокси-чеккер, и вот какая у меня появилась непонятка.
При помощи класса WebProxy я в несколько потоков коннектюсь к какому-то сайту, и все работает нормально, но, судя по сниферу, который у меня установлен, у меня идет всего 2 одновременных соединения, а мне нужно 50.

Почему оно одновременно поддерживает только два?
Ведь у меня в настройках ConnectionLimit выставлено все как положено:

```
Uri _Uri = new Uri(_url);
ServicePoint sUri = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(_Uri);
sUri.ConnectionLimit = 50;
```

Короче, вот сам код:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(_url);
 request.Method = "POST";  
   request.Timeout = 1800000;
    request.Accept = "**";
     request.KeepAlive = true;
      request.Proxy = new WebProxy("154.111.23.90",3128);
      byte[] _Data = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes("Test");
      request.ContentLength = _Data.Length;
     Stream sendStream = request.GetRequestStream();
   sendStream.Write(_Data,0,_Data.Length);
 sendStream.Close();
var response = request.GetResponse();
MessageBox.Show(response.ToString());
response.Close();
```

И вот что ещё интересно: когда коннектишься не через прокси, то есть через свой IP, то работает правильно, т.е. делает 50 соединений одновременно. А вот если через прокси - только 2.
Почему так, вообще непонятно. И они, кстати, эти соединения, как бы становятся на очередь, то есть сначала первые два соединения из пятидесяти коннектятся, потом следующие два, потом следующие, и следующие, и так далее, пока все 50, что я установил, не завершатся.
Но почему одновременно-то не хочет коннектить, неясно.
Приложение работает в многопоточном режиме асинхронно, в код выше я включил только самое основное, чтобы не забивать вам головы мусором.
Ну, вот такие дела. Кто, может, сталкивался или знает, как исправить, подскажите.

Comment: Может, вы упираетесь в лимит сайта? Допустим, прокси популярен, и сайт вводит ограничения на коннекты с него. Попробуйте для чистоты эксперимента поднять простенький прокси на соседнем хосте, и приконнектиться через него.

Comment: Не не не, проверяли, дело именно в моем приложении.

Answer (score 1):

[Приложения, использующие HTTP для подключения к ресурсам данных могут использовать классы ServicePoint и ServicePointManager платформы .NET Framework для управления подключения к Интернету и помочь их для достижения оптимальных масштабирования и производительности.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Ru-ru/library/7af54za5(v=vs.110).aspx)

> ServicePointManager статический класс, который управляет созданием и
>   разрушение экземпляров ServicePoint. ServicePointManager создает
>   ServicePoint если приложение запрашивает интернет-ресурс, который
>   отсутствует в коллекции существующих экземпляров
>   ServicePoint.Экземпляры ServicePoint уничтожаются при их превышали их
>   максимальное время простоя или если количество существующих
>   экземпляров ServicePoint превышает максимальное количество экземпляров
>   ServicePoint для приложения.Можно вести наблюдение и по умолчанию
>   максимальное время бездействия и максимальное число экземпляров
>   ServicePoint  путем установки свойства MaxServicePointIdleTime и
>   MaxServicePoints на ServicePointManager.
>
> Количество связь между клиентом и сервером может иметь драматический
>   влияние на пропускную способность приложения.По умолчанию приложение с
>   помощью класса HttpWebRequest использует до 2 постоянных подключений к
>   данному серверу, но можно задать максимальное число соединений на
>   основе в- приложения.

```
// Set the maximum number of connections per server to 4.
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 4;
```

или

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/");
ServicePoint sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri);
sp.ConnectionLimit = newLimit;
```